# Issue with Setting a Minimum Value for an ODE Solution using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numba, ode

I am working on a problem that involves solving a set of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) using `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` in Python. The ODE system is defined in a function `sys2` decorated with `@numba.njit` for performance reasons (actually, I do not know if this may affect my issue or how much it improves the overall efficiency)

My challenge arises from a requirement that one of the elements of the derivative vector, specifically `dydt[1]`, should never fall below (the arbitrary value) 0.005 in the iterations of the solution. I know that imposing this artificial boundary will affect the solution of the ODE but it should not be below 0, because it makes no physical sense in my system. I suspect that the solution is jumping to under 0 values due to the step size and the nature of the ODE system.

Here is the relevant part of the code that calculates `dydt`:

```
@numba.njit
def sys2(t, y, k=1, mu1=1, mu2=1, Ks1=1, Ks2=1, YXs1=1, YXs2=1, ms1=1, ms2=1, G=0, M=0 ):
    y1, y2, y3, y4 = y
    q1 = mu1 * ((y1 / (y1 + Ks1)) - ms1 * YXs1)
    q2 = mu2 * ((y2 / (y2 + (Ks2 / Ks1 * y1) )) - ms2 * YXs2)
    dydt = np.empty(4)
    dydt[0] = -q1 * y3
    dydt[1] = -q2 * y3
    dydt[2] = (YXs1 * q1 + YXs2 * q2) * y3
    dydt[3] = k * (0.0083 - y4) - (0.481 * (q1 + q2) * y3)
    return dydt
```

And here is the line that calls the solve_ivp with the function to solve:

```py
sol = solve_ivp(sys2, t_span, y0, method='DOP853',args = args)
```

I have also tried modifying the solving method for the ODE with the ones that support `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` and none of them seem to affect it, despite modifying the step size for the solution.

I have tried different approaches to set a lower limit for `dydt[1]` during the solution of the ODEs, but none of them seem to work. I have tried eliminating the numba decorator but it does not seem to affect the result in any way.

I'm looking for a way to prevent `dydt[1]` from falling below 0.005 when `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` solves the ODEs. It's important to note that I cannot directly set a lower limit for `dydt[1]` inside the `sys2` function since it will be overwritten in the next iteration by `solve_ivp`.

If everything goes as I want, the solver should identify if the solution of that vector is under a specific threshold, correct it, and use this corrected value in the next iteration. It should be small enough to not affect the overall solution.

Comment: If the value going below 0.005 doesn't make physical sense, then your ODEs should prevent this. A valid ODE describing a system supplied with valid initial conditions and constants should produce valid results.